# How can I validate DBRefs in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: validation, mongodb, dbref

Assuming I've got a MongoDB instance with 2 collections - *places* and *people*.

A typical *places* document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "someID"
    "name": "Broadway Center"
    "url": "bc.example.net"
}
```

And a *people* document looks like:

```
{
    "name": "Erin"
    "place": DBRef("places", "someID")
    "url":  "bc.example.net/Erin"
}
```

Is there any way to validate the *places* DBRef of **every** document in the *people* collection?

Comment: Only by manually picking out the documents and querying for the next collections document existance.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but make sure you need DBRef rather than simply storing a document ID. DBRef is only a good choice if you are not sure in which logical database the document is that is being referred to. Both options require manual querying for the referred document (although some higher level libraries will do that for you).

Comment: Thanks for the tip; DBRefs are in-fact required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's **no official/built-in method** to test the validity of DBRefs, so the validation must be performed manually.

I wrote a small script - *validateDBRefs.js*:

```
var returnIdFunc = function(doc) { return doc._id; };

var allPlaceIds  = db.places.find({}, {_id: 1} ).map(returnIdFunc);

var peopleWithInvalidRefs = db.people.find({"place.$id": {$nin: allPlaceIds}}).map(returnIdFunc);

print("Found the following documents with invalid DBRefs");
var length = peopleWithInvalidRefs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    print(peopleWithInvalidRefs[i]);
}
```

That when run with:

> mongo DB_NAME validateDBRefs.js

Will output:

> Found the following documents with invalid DBRefs
>
> 513c4c25589446268f62f487
>
> 513c4c26589446268f62f48a

Answer (score 1):

you could add a stored function for that. please note that the mongo documentation discourages the use of stored functions. You can read about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/server-side-javascript/#storing-functions-server-side)

In essence you create a function:

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id : "myAddFunction" ,
     value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }
   }
);
```

and once the function is created you can use it in your where clauses. So you could write a function that checks for the existence of the id in the dbRef.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Because it's an operation that won't be executed very often, I'll just write a script and manually evaluate it.